# C# Weird Encoding.Default.GetString output converting camera photo to string

Tags: c#, xamarin, encoding, encode

I have an `image` called in byte array form called `imageAsBytes` that I am trying to convert into a string stored in `machine.photos` using `Encoding.Default.GetString(image)`. The conversion is going wrong and I am getting some weird output.

`System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(image);` is returning this
[image]

Why is it not converting correctly? Here is the code I'm using to create the picture

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
            new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = true,
            });

 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                //file.Dispose();
                imageAsBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                file.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Why not correctly? What is your desired output? Have you tried other encodings instead of the default?

Comment: Hi Andrew, the correct output would be something like this `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAIAAAD91JpzAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAEnQAABJ0Ad5mH3gAAAAMSURBVBhXY0ACDAwAAA4AAXqxuTAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=` so far this is the only encoding I've tried but interestingly it was working previously

Comment: I have just tried it with C#'s Encoding.UTF8 and I am seeing the same issue

Comment: That output seems to belong to a PNG file instead of JPEG, but it is a Base 64 String, so I guess that's the encoding you want.

Comment: `Encoding.GetString` converts the sequence of bytes *for the specific character encoding*. JPEG (or PNG) or whatever image raw data is effectively "random data" in this regard - the sequence of bytes do *not* represent encoding strings. (The encoder can/will lose data or otherwise fail.)

Comment: Why has this been downvoted..?

Comment: @BarneyChambers, did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you want a Base 64 string encoding. You can get that with this:

```
string encoding = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
```

This format is useful to convert binary data in a readable and printable string. It will however occupy more as you are using a base 64 system instead of a base 256 one (bytes!). This will increase your data size in approximately 33%.

According to the MSDN:

> The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero are the uppercase
>   characters "A" to "Z", the lowercase characters "a" to "z", the
>   numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/". The valueless
>   character, "=", is used for trailing padding.

For example, `iVBORw0KGgoA` (the first 12 characters of your sample) represent 9 bytes. If you use any of the `Encoding` methods, those bytes will be converted to the corresponding encoding, which can be one character per byte (ASCII or UTF8), per 2 bytes (Unicode) or even per 4 bytes (UTF32). This means that 2 or 4 of your bytes can end up as one single Chinese symbol, which apparently is not what you want.